# Python Return Invalid Syntax Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi

I am writing a simple python program on a raspberry pi and I am quite new to python programming. I have defined a function called GetMessage which has no parameters and returns a variable which I called data, but I am getting an error which states

> File "Raspberry_pi.py", line 39
>
> return none
>
> ```
>     ^
> ```
>
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

```
import os
import glob
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from math import *
from bluetooth import *
from RPIO import PWM

os.system('sudo hciconfig hci0 pisca')
os.system('sudo hciconfig hci0 name "De Quadcoptur"')
servo = PWM.Servo()
StartSpin()

server_sock=BluetoothSocket( RFCOMM )
server_sock.bind(("",PORT_ANY))
server_sock.listen(1)

port = server_sock.getsockname()[1]

GetMessage()
DecodeInput()

uuid = "94f39d29-7d6d-437d-973b-fba39e49d4ee"
def GetMessage():
    advertise_service( server_sock, "XT1032", #phone bluetooth name
        service_id = uuid,
        service_classes = [ uuid, SERIAL_PORT_CLASS ],
        profiles = [ SERIAL_PORT_PROFILE ],
        #protocols = [ OBEX_UUID ]
        )
    client_sock, client_info = server_sock.accept()

    try:
            data = client_sock.recv(1024)
            if len(data) == 0: break
            print "received [%s]" % data
            client_sock.close()
            server_sock.close()
    except IOError:
        pass

        break
    return data


def StartSpin():
    # Set servo on GPIO17 to 1200µs (1.2ms)
    servo.set_servo(17, 1000)
    servo.set_servo(18, 1000)
    servo.set_servo(19, 1000)
    servo.set_servo(20, 1000)
    time.sleep(1)
    servo.stop_servo(17)
    servo.stop_servo(18)
    servo.stop_servo(19)
    servo.stop_servo(20)
    #Check if more pulses is faster
    time.sleep(2000)
    PWM.add_channel_pulse(0, 17, start = 1000, width = 100)
    PWM.add_channel_pulse(0, 17, start = 1000, width = 100)
    PWM.add_channel_pulse(0, 17, start = 1000, width = 100)
    PWM.add_channel_pulse(0, 17, start = 1000, width = 100)
    PWM.add_channel_pulse(0, 17, start = 1000, width = 100)
    servo.stop_servo(17)
    servo.stop_servo(18)
    servo.stop_servo(19)
    servo.stop_servo(20)
    return None

def DecodeInput():
    data = GetMessage()
    if(data == 'start')
        StartSpin()
        return 0
    else if(data[0] == 'U')
        data.strip('U')
        UpPower = int(data)
        SetUpPower(UpPower)
    else if(data[0] == 'P')
        data.strip('P')
        PitchPower = int(data)
        SetPitchPower
    else
        data.strip('P')
        RollPower = int(data)
    SetPower(UpPower, PitchPower, RollPower)
    return None

def SetPower(UpPower, PitchPower, RollPower):
    #Make Arbitrary Values
    Motor1Power = UpPower #Front Left
    Motor2Power = UpPower #Front Right
    Motor3Power = UpPower #Back  Left
    Motor4Power = UpPower #Back  Right
    PitchPower = PitchPower /2
    RollPower = RollPower /2
    if(PitchPower < 25)
        Motor1Power = Motor1Power + abs(25-PitchPower)
        Motor2Power = Motor1Power + abs(25-PitchPower)
    else
        Motor3Power = Motor3Power + (PitchPower-25)
        Motor4Power = Motor4Power + (PitchPower-25)
    if(RollPower < 25)
        Motor1Power = Motor1Power + abs(25-RollPower)
        Motor3Power = Motor3Power + abs(25-RollPower)
    else
        Motor2Power = Motor2Power + (RollPower - 25)
        Motor4Power = Motor4Power + (RollPower - 25)
```

What is causing this error and how can I fix it?

Edit: I have defined data as a global variable and the error now is

> File "Raspberry_pi.py", line 39
>
> return data
>
> ```
>     ^
> ```
>
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Post the whole file. Where is line 39?

Comment: And fix your indentation

Comment: line 39 is "return data"

Comment: Well, it'd be good to view the part of the code that contains `return none`. You only have `return data`.

Comment: @Root0x Your error message says otherwise. Please post the whole file unmodified and fix your indentation as Michael suggested.

Comment: If it really is `return none`, it should be `return None`. Python is case-sensitive.

Comment: just added the entire code

Comment: Indentation is still incorrect. Python has strict indentation guidelines or the code will not work properly (syntax errors and runtime errors). In many editors you can select-all and TAB to indent a full space, which will make pasting here on StackO much easier.

Comment: If I fix the indentation of the code, I get a syntax error at a different location, due to the missing colon at the end of your `if` statement. You'll also get errors from `else if` lines (which should be `elif` and have a colon at the end of the line) and the `else` (which just needs a colon). `SetPitchPower` by itself on a line is probably not going to cause an exception, but probably doesn't do what you want.

Comment: where exactly is the indentation wrong?

Comment: Basically, your indentation is off everywhere. Especially at the function levels. If you define a function, the entire function must be indented.

Comment: Your indentation may only be wrong in the code we see on Stack Overflow, not in the copy you're running on your system. Use the `{}` code button in the editor to format all of the code at once, rather than manually indenting the top level lines (which will break their indentation relative to the rest of the code).

Comment: maybe @Blckknght could post the correctly indented code?

Comment: @cod3monk3y: The trouble with that is that I may not be indenting correctly. I only fixed the obvious indentation issues with the functions (back when there was much less code in the question).

Comment: now i have shown my correct indentation

Comment: @Blckknght: most certainly understood

Comment: is the indentation correct now?

Comment: Looks much better. Check out @Blackknght 's comment regarding colons, above.

Comment: yep ive now added colons and ive just found out that else if is not a python statement but still the error about return data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of syntax problems in your code. Because of the nature of `SyntaxError` exceptions (which are raised when the interpreter doesn't understand the code syntax), the error messages may not identify the right line as the source of the problem.

The first syntax error I see is that you're using `break` in the `GetMessage` function without it being in a loop. A `break` statement is only useful within a `for` or `while` block, and using one elsewhere (in an `except` block in this case) is a syntax error.

The next set of errors have to do with missing colons. Each of the conditional branches in `DecodeInput` and `SetPower` need to have a colon after the condition: `if condition1:`, `elif condition2:`, `else:`

It's also an error to use `else if` rather than `elif` (you could make it work if you added a colon, a newline and an extra level of indentation after `else:`, then used a separate `if` statement, but that would be wasteful of space).

There are some additional issues, but they're not syntax errors. For instance, you're calling your functions from top-level code before they've been defined, and `DecodeInput` has a line with the bare expression `SetPower` which doesn't do anything useful (you probably want to call `SetPower` with some argument).

Hopefully this will get you on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

Once you get your colons fixed, you'll probably run into a problem with your `GetMessage` syntax. You cannot `break` unless you're inside of a loop. If you intend to return from an exception, you don't need the `pass` call. An example (simplified from your code) of how this method could (should?) look:

```
def GetMessage():
    data = None

    try:
        data = [1,2]
        if len(data) == 0: 
            return None
    except IOError:
        return None

    return data
```

Clearly you'll want to replace the bulk of the method with your own code, and determine if you really want to `return` from the function at the points where you put `break`s.